# Call DataTables export functions from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, datatables

The DataTables [buttons extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) allows users to export the table data to CSV, Excel, etc. There are [examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/config) in the documentation that show how to style the button elements.

What I want to do though is to be able to call the export functions from menu buttons in a Floating Action Button. I could move and restyle the DataTables buttons every time the data table gets redrawn, but is there an easier way?

In particular, is there a way to call the export functions directly from JavaScript?

Comment: You could always just do `$('#floatingBtn').click(function(){ $('#someExportBtn').click(); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple what @DelightedD0D said in his comment:

> You could always just do
>
> `$('#floatingBtn').click(function(){ $('#someExportBtn').click(); });`

... with some CSS to force the original buttons out of view off-screen and you'd wind up with only one set of buttons being shown.

```
.buttons-html5, .buttons-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense - is there an advantage to setting `left: -9999px` instead of just setting `display: hidden` ?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think the click event may not work in all browsers with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.

Answer (score 8):

You can manually trigger the event of the button you wish to 'click'.

**Example:**

```
var myDataTable1 = $('#dt1').DataTable({
   buttons: [
      'excelHtml5'
   ]
});

// Use jQuery selector (in this case looking for known class name) for the hidden button, then trigger it's action event.
myDataTable1.buttons('.buttons-excel').trigger();
```

**Extra:** Based on the above example, here's a quick and dirty little function you can use.

```
//example: TriggerDataTableButton(myDataTable1, '.buttons-excel');
function TriggerDataTableButton(dataTable, buttonSelector) {
   dataTable.buttons(buttonSelector).trigger();
};
```