# Get HTML table values for excel export - from: input.value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a table in HTML that I need to convert into excel to complete an order to be sent as eMail attachment.

The table itself is a basket for orders. The client adds the products, the page loads more details from the database (most of the HTML table code is produced in C#). Some Javascript to update the total based on the quantity, etc.

Problem is that for my order report I need to extract all info from different scenarios. Some info is inside the tag, some other is in the “value” propertie and some is modified with javascript.

Most examples in stackOverflow are about getting the info from the tag and totally impossible to adapt to my need.

I have already rebuilt the code for this specific page twice so I wouldn’t be surprised if someone says the structure is all wrong and I need to do it another way.

Am I using inputs wrong?

```
<table id="tableReport" class="tablePanier">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="titles">GenCod</th>
      <th class="titles">Auteur</th>
      <th class="titles">Titre</th>
      <th class="titles">Quantite</th>
      <th class="titles">PrixTTC</th>
      <th class="titles">TotalPrixTTC</th>
      <th class="titles">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_hover">
      <td>9782871428374</td>
      <td>WARNES, TIM</td>
      <td>FICHU CANETON</td>
      <td>
        <input
          id="Quantity9782871428374"
          onclick="ReCalculateTotal(9782871428374)"
          value="1"
          min="1"
          type="number"
          name="fname"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
        />
      </td>
      <td id="Prix_TTC">
        <input
          id="Prix_TTC9782871428374"
          type="text"
          value="5.2"
          name="Prix_TTC"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
          disabled=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          id="Total9782871428374"
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          value="5.2"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
          disabled=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="../panierdecommande.aspx?remove=9782871428374">
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Retirer"
            name="fname"
            style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
        /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_hover">
      <td>9791021406605</td>
      <td>Cuenca, Catherine</td>
      <td>REINE MARGOT (LA)</td>
      <td>
        <input
          id="Quantity9791021406605"
          onclick="ReCalculateTotal(9791021406605)"
          value="1"
          min="1"
          type="number"
          name="fname"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
        />
      </td>
      <td id="Prix_TTC">
        <input
          id="Prix_TTC9791021406605"
          type="text"
          value="12.95"
          name="Prix_TTC"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
          disabled=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          id="Total9791021406605"
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          value="12.95"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
          disabled=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="../panierdecommande.aspx?remove=9791021406605">
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Retirer"
            name="fname"
            style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
        /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line_hover">
      <td>9782371262737</td>
      <td>Stone, Liv</td>
      <td>Initie-moi. Mes jours contre tes nuits</td>
      <td>
        <input
          id="Quantity9782371262737"
          onclick="ReCalculateTotal(9782371262737)"
          value="1"
          min="1"
          type="number"
          name="fname"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
        />
      </td>
      <td id="Prix_TTC">
        <input
          id="Prix_TTC9782371262737"
          type="text"
          value="14.9"
          name="Prix_TTC"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
          disabled=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          id="Total9782371262737"
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          value="14.9"
          style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
          disabled=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="../panierdecommande.aspx?remove=9782371262737">
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Retirer"
            name="fname"
            style=" width: 100px;  text-align: center; "
        /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you importing the table into excel? Depending on which table-to-excel technique you use and what kind of data formats it supports, you could have the database return the same info in a format the excel understands. If you are forced to supply a html table, just replace all the inputs with their actual values before sending the html to excel.

Comment: "just replace all the inputs with their actual values before sending the html to excel"... hehe not a bad idea. I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Depends on the rest of the app. I just have the server have two table templates. One for use in the app and one for use with export to things that don't understand json. So when I need to turn the data into excel, I just tell the server to use the basic table template instead of the app version. The 'quick fix' is using your favourite selector function to get all the inputs in the table and then loop over them, changing the innerHTML of their parent element ( the <td> tag they're inside ) into the value attribute of the input.

Comment: Favorite Selector Function? i am thinking about getting all HTML Table code into a string variable in Javascript and then replace the input by the value. Am i right?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll( '#tableReport input' );` or `document.getElementById( 'tableReport' ).getElementsByTagName( 'input' );` will give you a (live ) nodelist of the inputs inside the html table. So you could make a function that does that before using the table in excel. But how and when exactly depends on "what your html-to-excel parser needs". Your string method would work as well, but will be more complicated when your users start typing stuff like `<` or like other language symbols into your inputs. Personally I would change the C# code somehow so it's compatible with the excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189889/discussion-between-rui-ruivo-and-shilly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery datatable for solution

For example:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

You can trigger the standard button if you want.
[Call DataTables export functions from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005053/call-datatables-export-functions-from-javascript)